# React-pdf/renderer loads correctly the first time, but then loads entire app (starting at login page) after closing and reopening

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, pdf, react-pdf

I am using React-pdf/renderer to render invoice PDFs, varying on which invoice the user wants to view. On the first pdf view it works, however after closing the dialog window and attempting to view the same PDF or another, it displays my entire application.

### Here is my dialog component contained within my invoice component:

```
<Dialog aria-label="pdf-modal" className={classes.modalContent} fullScreen open={viewPDF} onClose={handlePDFClose} TransitionComponent={Transition}>
  <AppBar className={classes.appBar}>
    <Toolbar>
      <IconButton edge="start" color="inherit" onClick={handlePDFClose} aria-label="close">
        <CloseIcon />
      </IconButton>
      <Typography variant="h6" className={classes.title}>
        Invoice PDF
      </Typography>
    </Toolbar>
  </AppBar>
  <PDFViewer className={classes.pdfViewer}>
    <InvoicePDF
      invoice={modalContent}
      items={state.inventory}
      account={state.accounts?.filter(x => x.accountID === modalContent.accountID)[0]}
      taxRate={taxRate}
      credits={invoiceCredits}
    />
  </PDFViewer>
</Dialog>
```

### And here is my InvoicePDF Component, which utitlizes other child components for rendering:

```
const InvoicePDF = (props: {
    invoice: InvoiceModel,
    items: ItemModel[],
    taxRate: number,
    account: AccountModel,
    credits: number
  
    }) => {

    const { invoice, items, taxRate, account, credits} = props;

    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <Document aria-label="pdf-document">
          <Page size="A4" style={styles.page}>
            <InvoiceTitle title='Invoice'/>
            <InvoiceNo invoice={invoice}/>
            <BillTo account={account}/>
            <InvoiceItemsTable 
              invoice={invoice} 
              items={items}
              taxRate={taxRate}
              credits={credits}
            />
          </Page>
        </Document>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
}
```

### I am also receiving these messages in the console:

asm.js type error: Disabled because no suitable wasm compiler is available 2.9353cd33.chunk.js

Warning: Invalid absolute docBaseUrl: "blob:http://localhost:5000/9b5ed5ee-c427-4464-ab7b-abdefb835d35". pdf.worker.js:1076:13

PDF f4cdab794e2e1f6ec4f52956dab2fcf1 [1.3 react-pdf / react-pdf] (PDF.js: 2.9.273)

This is the first time I am working with PDFs so this issue is really perplexing me, don't understand how the dialog can display the full application after reload/not load the correct PDF. Any help would be great and if I need to provide any more information please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: wondering if you had managed to fix the issue. if so can you share what worked for you.